# How do I catch javascript code injection in URL using python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, url, xss

How do I detect malformed URLs, or URLs with javascript injected in them

```
'http://example.com/portal/image/user_male_portrait?img_id=755109&t=1372243875358"><script>setTimeout(function () {document.body.innerHTML = \'<img src="http://images.example.com:9191/public/rickroll.gif" style="display: block; width: 100%">\'; }, 100);</script><!--'

'http://example.com/portal/image/user_male_portrait?img_id=566203&t=1350313911834'
```

The first URL is malicious while the second one is not. I want to be able to flag the first one. I can use regex to match script tags I suppose but is this the way to do it with Python?

Comment: most templating libraries have protections built in that disallow malicious variable data (unless you explicitly mark something as "safe")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really hard to do a regular expression that would know if an URL is an attempt at script injection or not. To match the example you gave, searching for `<script` would be enough.

But a `<script>` tag is not the only dangerous thing in HTML: consider for example the URL `http://example.com/portal/image/user_male_portrait?img_id=755109&t=1372243875358" onclick="setTimeout(function () { document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="http://images.example.com:9191/public/rickroll.gif" style="display: block; width: 100%">'; }, 100);"`.  There is no `<script>` tag at all.

---

All in all, the only thing really can do in regex is to reject any URL that matches

```
(?i)^(?!\s*https?://)|[<>"']
```

That is reject any URL where there is `<>"'` in bare; and reject all URLs that start with anything else than the regex `https?://` (after all, even with the previous check, I could still do

```
javascript:alert(Object.keys({gotcha:42}))
```

---

However, *if* this is a case of input sanitization, then do note that one can also always percent-encode `<`, `>`, `"` and `'` in *any* URL without damage, so maybe:

```
url.replace('<', '%3C').replace('>', '%3E')\
   .replace('"', '%22').replace("'", '%27')
```

is a more sensible thing to do (along with checking that the `scheme` indeed is either `"http:"` or `"https:"`). Or use `urllib.parse.urlparse` to split the URL into components, then decode and re-encode it, and finally use `urllib.parse.urlunparse` to make it into a URL again.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. As for urlparse are you suggesting that I look at the individual components and perform regex matching on them

Comment: nope, I am just sayin' that if all that you want is to safeguard something, then you should transform the URLs, not reject. See also Joran's valid comment on that this should be a non-issue anyway.

Comment: Well to provide you the scenario. The system currently stores the url into a db and I just want to throw and alert if it catches an injection when the user is providing the url. I am not using any templating library